# What to Implement When Deriving From System.Web.Mvc.Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am wanting to create a custom HandleErrorAction attribute and apply it to a base contoller class. However, I am running into issues right away when I extend Controller.

For example, I created the below controller.

```
public CMSController : Controller
{
    ...nothing implemented, just extended (and I did call base constructor as well - no args though
}
```

Now, I assumed I could simply do

```
public class YearsController : CMSController
{
    ...
}
```

and move merrily along with action, route, etc. handling from the base class.

But, I am getting an exception:

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'YearsController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Index() on type CMS.WebUI.Controllers.YearsController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Index(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]) on type CMS.WebUI.Controllers.CMSController

So, I ask. What must I implement for this to work? When extending from Controller, do I need to rewrite router handling, etc?

If not, what is wrong?

Much obliged.

Comment: Remove the Index method from the base controller. The View will be returned by the YearsController.

Comment: @GiorgioMinardi I do not have any methods defined in CMSController - my base class. It is simply derived from Controller. I then derived my YearsController from CMSController.

Comment: Yeah...well it seems I had created a test controller very early on called CMSController in the Controllers folder...yeah...duplicate controller name. Stupud mistake. Just wow. I figured it out after rereading your comment. Thanks.